# builtins.NameError: name 'guess' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-defined-functions, nameerror

I was working on a lab assignment and I've been struggling with an error for days. I coded return as well in my function and it keeps saying there's a `NameError:` and I didn't define it.

Here's the code I'm working on and it's all messed up since I'm not done. But I'd love to know what did I messed up and how can I fix the name error. Thanks!

```
import random

def main():
    instructions = display_instructions("instructions.txt")


    #display instructions
    display_instructions(instructions)


    list_of_words = ['apple', 'banana', 'watermelon', 'kiwi', 'pineapple', 
                 'mango']

    correct_word=random.choice(list_of_words)
    answer = list(correct_word)

    puzzle = []
    puzzle.extend(answer)

    display_puzzle_string(puzzle)

    play_game(puzzle, answer)

    display_result(is_win, answer)


    input('Press enter to end the game.')

def display_instructions(filename):
    instruction_file=open("instructions.txt","r")
    file_contents=instruction_file.read()
    instruction_file.close()
    print(file_contents)


def display_puzzle_string(puzzle):
    for i in range(len(puzzle)):
        puzzle[i] = '_'
    print('The answer so far is '+" ".join(puzzle))


def play_game(puzzle, answer):
    num_guesses = 4    
    while num_guesses > 0:
        get_guess(num_guesses)
        update_puzzle_string(puzzle, answer, guess)
        display_puzzle_string(puzzle)
    is_word_found(puzzle)


def get_guess(num_guesses):
    guess=input('Guess a letter '+'('+str(num_guesses)+' guesses remaining):')
    return guess


def update_puzzle_string(puzzle, answer, guess):
    for i in range(len(answer)):
                if guess.lower() == answer[i]:
                    puzzle[i] = guess.lower()
                    num_guesses += 1    
    return puzzle


 def is_word_found(puzzle):
    if puzzle == answer:
        return is_win


def display_result(is_win, answer):
    if is_win:
        print('Good job! You found the word '+correct_word+'!')

    else: 
        print('Not quite, the correct word was '+correct_word+
          '. Better luck next time')

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has different flaws. The main errors are related to indentation and function scopes. Keep in mind that Python uses indentation to group statements. Use 4 spaces consistently as indentation for grouping statements, e.g. to indent the function body, for-loop body etc.

Furthermore, there are many `undefined name` errors in your code, since you refer to names that are not defined in the current scope. Consider your function `is_word_function(puzzle)`:

```py
def is_word_found(puzzle):
    if puzzle == answer:
        return is_win
```

The name `answer` is defined in `main()`, whereas `is_win` is not defined at all (you are passing it to `display_result()` in `main()`, but have not defined it before). A better function declaration would look like this

```py
def is_word_found(puzzle, answer):
    return puzzle == answer
```

Note that this suggestion aims to be educational, I don't think that you necessarily need a function for this.

Generally, in order for names to be available in the current (function) scope, you have to either pass arguments to the function, or put them at module level, or - even better - consider looking into OOP (which, since this is a lab assignment, I suppose you haven't done yet).

Once you fixed these errors and your code compiles, you need to work on the logic of your game.
For example in `play_game`, you have the loop `while num_guesses > 0` which will run infinitely, since you never decrease the `num_guesses` counter (in fact, you increase it in `update_puzzle_string`. A better loop would look like this:

```py
def play_game(puzzle, answer, ..):
    num_guesses = 4
    while num_guesses and not is_word_found(puzzle, answer):
        # logic
        num_guesses -= 1

# or, alternatively
def play_game(puzzle, answer, ..):
    num_guesses = 4
    for _ in range(num_guesses):
        # logic
        if is_word_found(puzzle, answer):
            # break or return
```

Consider to use `flake8` in order to validate your code, detect errors and non-pythonic code constructs in the future.

```py
>>> pip3 install flake8
>>> flake8 your_file.py
```

Answer (score 0):

In the function `play_game`, you have the line `get_guess(num_guesses)` which returns the variable guess. However, you are not assigning the guess to a variable in the function. You can fix this by changing that line to `guess = get_guess(num_guesses)`. The error tells you exactly what is wrong. You have not defined the variable `guess` so far.